# Subtract elements in an array

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-cursoradapter

I have an array with this values 80 82 84 90 94 is it possible to subtract the values so the output could be 0 2 2 6 4?
I´ve edited the question:Now I want to use this in an android cursor adapter but I´m getting index out of bounds when it reaches the calculation of the difference.

```
   public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {

        // here we are setting our data
        // that means, take the data from the cursor and put it in views

            double weight = cursor.getDouble(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(DbHelper.ENTRY_USER_WEIGHT));



            int count=cursor.getCount();
            Double[] input = new Double[count];
            // Obtaining the number of records


            System.out.println("number of records "+input.length);
            // Array for storing differences

            double[] difference= new double[count ];

            difference [0] = 0; // First record difference is 0 only
            int i;
             // Looping number of records times
           for(  i=0; i<count-1 ;i++)
             {        

                    input[i]=weight;
                    System.out.println("i value"+i);
                  System. out.println(""+input[i]);
                 // Difference = next record - current record
               difference [i]= input [i+1] - input[i];
               //  System.out.println ("Difference between "+input [i+1]+ " and  "+input[i] + " is : " +difference[i]);

             }
```

Comment: what is the relationship between these two arrays.

Comment: @user3218114 - subtracting `diffs[1] - diffs[0]`, `diffs[2] - diffs[1]` (although I don't know from where the `0` came :P). This is pretty simple, why not loop from 1 to n-1 and try `arr[counter]-arr[counter-1]` ?

Comment: http://java-demos.blogspot.in/2012/11/subtract-elements-in-array-in-java.html

Answer (score 1):

```
        // Setting the input array.
        int input[]=     {80, 82, 84, 90, 94};

        // Obtaining the number of records
        int noOfRecords = input.length;

        // Array for storing differences
        double[] difference= new double[noOfRecords ];

        difference [0] = 0; // First record difference is 0 only

         // Looping number of records times
         for( int i=0; i < noOfRecords -1 ;i++)
         {       
             // Difference = next record - current record
             difference [i+1]= input [i+1] - input[i];
             System.out.println ("Difference between "+input [i+1]+ " and  "+input[i] + " is : " +difference[i+1]);
         } 

         System.out.println("My final difference array Output is : "+java.util.Arrays.toString( difference ));
```

---

**OUTPUT:**

```
Difference between 82 and  80 is : 2.0
Difference between 84 and  82 is : 2.0
Difference between 90 and  84 is : 6.0
Difference between 94 and  90 is : 4.0
My final difference array Output is : [0.0, 2.0, 2.0, 6.0, 4.0]
```

---

If you replace  `double[] difference = new double[noOfRecords ];` by

```
int [] difference = new int [noOfRecords];
```

You get an output exactly as you wanted :

```
Difference between 82 and  80 is : 2
Difference between 84 and  82 is : 2
Difference between 90 and  84 is : 6
Difference between 94 and  90 is : 4
My difference array Output is : [0, 2, 2, 6, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Logic:
for array  `Arr[] = {80 82 84 90 94}`
Required output = `{0,2,2,6,4}`

Sol:

```
output[0] = 0; 
for( i=1;i<cursor.getCount();i++)
{       
    output[i] = Arr[i]-Arr[i-1];
}
```

Note that the output array elements are obtained by subtracting current index element with the element at previous index.
Example 82-80 =2, 84-82=2, 90-84=6 and 94-90=4

Answer (score 0):

You can subtract a number from its next number.

```
int[] numbers={80, 82, 84, 90, 94};
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if(i < numbers.length - 1)
        System.out.println(numbers[i + 1] - numbers[i]);
}
}
```

Output-

```
2
2
6
4
```